# String replace function

Tags: java, string

I have following string

```
String str = "replace :) :) with some other string";
```

And I want to replace first occurance of `:)` with some other string

And I used `str.replaceFirst(":)","hi");`

it gives following exception

> "Unmatched closing ')'"

I tried using `replace` function but it replaced all occurance of `:)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Apache Jakarta Commons](http://commons.apache.org/) are often the solution for this class of problems. In this case, I would have a look at [commons-lang](http://commons.apache.org/lang/), espacially [StringUtils.replaceOnce()](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.3/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html#replaceOnce(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)).

Answer (score 10):

The `replaceFirst` method takes a regular expression as its first parameter. Since `)` is a special character in regular expressions, you must quote it. Try:

```
str.replaceFirst(":\\)", "hi");
```

The double backslashes are needed because the double-quoted string also uses backslash as a quote character.

Comment: Compiles fine for me - check that you haven't made the same error elsewhere.

Answer (score 5):

The first argument to replaceFirst() is a regular expression, not just a character sequence. In regular expressions, the parantheses have special significance. You should escape the paranthesis like this:

```
str = str.replaceFirst(":\\)", "hi");
```